# Loop through a 2d array backwards

Tags: java, arrays

I need to loop through a 2d array backwards for a little map project I'm doing. I tried doing so based off of what I've read online, but my 2d array is different. How can I loop through this backwards?

```
for(int i = 0;  i < map.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
        switch (nmap[j][i]) {
            map[i][j] = new Tile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By backwards do you mean from `map[N][M]` to `map[0][0]` (where `N` is the number of rows and `M` is the number of columns)?

Answer (score 2):

To go the other way, you need to start the index at the highest value and decrease it for each iteration. Like this:

```
for (int i = map.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    for (int j = map[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        switch (map[i][j]) {
            map[i][j] = new Title();
        }
    }
```

Note that in both loops, we are starting from the highest index, map.length - 1 in the first and map[i].length in the second, and going down by one for each iteration until we reach the lowest index, 0 for both loops.

Answer (score 0):

With `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)`, you're starting at the start (`0`), and going to the end (`length`).

To go the other way, just reverse everything:

`for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Few things to note:

- We have to do `length - 1`, or we'll start 1 past the end
- We're using `>=` to include 0
- We're decrementing `i` instead of incrementing it.

If you need it for a 2D array, just add a second of the above for the second dimension.

Answer (score -1):

To go backwards , you need to read from the highest index to 0 . Highest index is typically length-1 since indices start from 0. Same goes for the inner j loop. Start from the highest index of map[i] i.e length -1.

eg. Array = [2 ,3,4,5,6]
Length =5 .Indices to iterate = 4 to 0 if backwards.

```
  for(int i = map.length-1;  i >= 0; i--) {
        for(int j = map[i].length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            //your operation
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mind to explain this a bit?

Comment: updated with the explanation. in case you are the downvoter and also to help the OP. sorry about that.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but thanks for the explanation. Don't be discouraged. Quality answers get upvotes.

Answer (score -3):

Here you go.

```
for(int i = map.length-1;  i >= 0; i--){
    for(int j = map[i].length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
         switch (nmap[j][i]) {
             map[i][j] = new Tile()
        }
    }
}
```

Rather then going from 0 to map.length and 0 to map[i].length, this program starts at map.length-1 (so you don't ever get an index out of bounds error) and continues until it hits zero.

Comment: -- Because this doesn't explain anything. If they're having problems understanding a `for` loop, I can't see this helping.

Comment: If they are having problems understanding a for loop they should not be on stack overflow.